# how could i make an exception for a file '.txt' in bash programming?

Tags: bash, for-loop, exception, jpeg

so the matter when i run the script is that it works very well but i just need that my program recognize file with '.jpg' extention and except any other file with a diferent extention:

so there is the code:

```
for i in $( cat list.txt );do

separate #create a div during the execution

addtags $i
echo "tags added [ $i ]"
done
```

and the error output:

```
Error: Writing of this type of file is not suported - list.txt
```

**PD: '''addtags''' just support '.jpg' files.**

Comment: so you want to skip a filename from `list.txt` if its extension is txt? Also, is `list.txt` a mere list of filenames, one on every line?

Answer (score 1):

First, don't use a `for` loop here (see [Bash FAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)). Second, you can use `bash`'s conditional command to match `i` against the pattern `*.jpg`, rejecting those files that to not match.

```
while IFS= read -r i; do
  [[ $i == *.jpg ]] || continue
  addtags "$i"
  echo "tags added [ $i ]"
done < file.txt
```

Comment: Another good link: [Why you don't read lines with "for"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).

Answer (score 0):

Use `grep`(or `grep -v`) for selecting the files you (don't) want:

```
while IFS= read -r file; do
  addtags "${file}"
  echo "tags added [ ${file} ]"
done < <(grep ".jpg$" file.txt)
```